# trying to upload image and have it update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert

Whenever I try to upload a file using a form and have it insert the file into mysql, I get these errors-

> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   /home/sgas/public_html/x/agentpage.php on line 300
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   /home/sgas/public_html/x/agentpage.php on line 305
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   /home/sgas/public_html/x/agentpage.php on line 310

I have looked over the names and they seem to all be right so I have no idea whats wrong right now :/.

Here is the code starting at the form where you upload the image.

```
<td align="right" valign="top" class="bodymaintextalt">applicable document</td>
<td>
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="35">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top" class="bodymaintextalt">received</td>
        <td>
            <input name="received" type="text" id="received" value="$">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top" class="bodymaintextalt">paid</td>
        <td>
            <input name="paid" type="text" id="paid" value="$">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <div align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit32" value="Submit">


<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxxx");

    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("xxxxx", $con);

    $target = "clientdoc/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['agentclient']);

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $propertydescription = $_POST['propertydescription'];
    $transactiontype = $_POST['transactiontype'];
    $applicabledocument = ($_FILES['file']['agentclient']); 
    $received = $_POST['received'];
    $paid = $_POST['paid'];

    //Writes the to the server 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 

        //Tells you if its all ok 
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['agentclient']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    } 
    else { 
        //Gives and error if its not 
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    } 

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactions` (`date`, `agentclient`, `propertydescription`, `transactiontype`, `applicabledocument`, `received`, `paid`) 
    VALUES ('$date', '$agentclient', '$propertydescription', '$transactiontype', '$applicabledocument', '$received', '$paid')") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"48\">";
        mysql_close($con);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form ..>` tag?

Comment: I think U haven't user `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I did that and now Im getting these errors

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: agentclient in /home/jjlliinn/public_html/manage/agentpage.php on line 300

Notice: Undefined index: agentclient in /home/jjlliinn/public_html/manage/agentpage.php on line 305

Warning: move_uploaded_file(clientdoc/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/jjlliinn/public_html/manage/agentpage.php on line 310

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpJAj5sS' to 'clientdoc/' in /home/jjlliinn/public_html/manage/agentpage.php on line 310

Comment: There is no predefined key `agentclient` in the `$_FILES[...]` superglobal  - ie. `$_FILES[...]['agentclient']` see the manual -  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php  There is only `name`, `type`, `size`, `tmp_name`, and `error`.

Comment: Alright, whew, now I am getting permissions denied errors

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/clientdoctinkertable_tx.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/jjlliinn/public_html/manage/agentpage.php on line,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I have made everything 777 already thought.

Comment: This warning shows file name `/clientdoctinkertable_tx.png` - `move_uploaded_file(/clientdoctinkertable_tx.png)`, but the code you posted does not have a `/` before `clientdoc`, but does after - `$target = "clientdoc/";` so somewhere you have an error in your code (or you did not post your actual code) as it should be something like `move_uploaded_file(clientdoc/tinkertable_tx.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file name is file so change it to agentclient so

```
<input type="file" name="agentclient" id="file"/>

$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['agentclient']['name']);
```

Comment: This is Incorrect/Wrong. If you change it to `type="file" name="agentclient"` then it would be `$_FILES['agentclient']` NOT `$_FILES['file']['agentclient']` http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php